# is it possible to provide artwork in a Playlist POST request?

Tags: api, soundcloud, artwork, playlists

Regarding the soundcloud API.. when posting PLAYLISTS.. is it possible to provide artwork? artwork_data does not seeem to be a valid property when uploading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, just provide the playlist[artwork_data] parameter. If you were doing it with curl for example:

```
curl -D - -X POST https://api.soundcloud.com/playlists.json -F'oauth_token=foo' \
      -F'playlist[title]=New Album' -F'playlist[sharing]=private' \
      -F'playlist[artwork_data]=@test.jpeg' -F'playlist[tracks][][id]=trackid'
```

I'll update the docs to make this more clear, as I notice that artwork_data is missing from the list of parameters in the documentation of the playlist endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have never been able to get this to work. Anytime I put playlist[artwork_data] property in the POST request it fails with response code 422.  Posting tracks with artwork works fine. The issue is only occurring with sets.

Comment: Paul -- can you help me figure this out?